# Windows Hotspot : share origin subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, printer, subnet

My router's got a problem : the WiFi emitter is dead.
The Ethernet's fine though.

So I'm using one PC (pretty old, has an RJ45 port) as a Mobile Hotspot. This creates a new subnet `192.137.145.0/24`

I've got my printer (`192.168.1.16`) on the router subnet (`192.168.1.0/24`) and I wish to print from a computer (`192.137.145.254`) connected to the hotspot (`192.137.145.1`).

Because of the subnets' masks, I can't access the printer from my PC.

So what command can I run on the hotspot one-leg-in-each-subnet computer so that I can access the router's subnet from the hotspot's subnet ? Something to do with `route` right?

Comment: How did you conclude "Because of the subnets' masks, I can't access the printer from my PC"?

Comment: Does it have to be Windows? // Getting a new router, even if just to play Wi-Fi Access Point, is a superior solution is every regard.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, yes @John and DanielB my ISP's is sending me a new router, will receive it tomorrow.

Comment: @user1686 hmm, basic networking knowledge... unless I'm mistaken

Comment: @Silloky: But you can access superuser.com even though it's some 10–20 subnets away from you. Is the problem that the OS cannot _find_ the printer on its own, or is the problem that you can't even reach it by exact IP address?

Comment: @John the DHCP on the router should do that automatically when it sets up

Comment: @user1686 hmm, good point. Doesn't the WAN have routers and switches everywhere to control the IP protocol ? The computer can't reach the exact IP because the subnet mask of this hotspot-network  won't allow access to local IPs with a difference in the first 3 bytes of the IP address.

Comment: @Silloky: That's not what subnet masks do, though. They don't limit access – they only tell the system what addresses are within the subnet or not. Your hotspot is the router that forwards packets between the subnet and "out of subnet" locations, _regardless_ of whether the destination is a 192.168 address or not. (Though I have to say "192.137.145" is a pretty odd choice – that's an address range belonging to HP Inc.)

Comment: @user1686 ok, i get it better now ! Well, in fact, the PC I am using as a hotspot is an HP ! Nice deductions !